# How to configure development environment

Tags: git, ftp, eclipse, windows-server-2012, iis

I am looking for feedback on setting up and configuring my development environement. Below is my current hardware and software:

**My local hardware and software:**

- PC laptop Eclipse IDE (Plugins listed below)

  - RSE (Remote System Explorer)
  - CFEditor (ColdFusion Plugin for color coding and code hints)

**Remote Software and Hardware:**

- Windows Server

  - Access to IIS Manager
  - Web application built in ColdFusion (Production)
  - Copy of the above application in a separate folder (Development)
  - Remote Desktop Access and FTP access
  - SQL Server - Different machine than the web server
  - Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
  - BitBucket (for git development)

**Best Case Scenario:**
I want my Eclipse IDE to load the development folder on the Windows server as a remote project. I want this remote project to work as if it was a standard  project (Which I am unable to configure). In a perfect world I would like to integrate BitBucket so that future development could be done in branches for easier tracking and uploading.

**What is happening so far:**
I can make a connection via the RSE plugin and I can access the files from the server but I want to save the connection as a project that can be accessed from the rest of Eclipse and other perspectives (not just the RSE perspective). [Work on a remote project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216822/work-on-a-remote-project-with-eclipse-via-ssh)

I am also unable to make the connection to BitBucket from Eclipse so that updates made to my development files will also update my base files on BitBucket.

If anyone can help with the configuration or provide feedback or any other information would be great.

Comment: The whole advantage of git is that you can work on everything locally and then push the changes to the remote. While git integration in an IDE can be helpful, it's by no means necessary. You just need to figure out what local-config-specific files your IDE adds to the project and add those to the .gitignore, then make commits using git bash.

Comment: you really are better off working on the project locally and then uploading data as needed. Many eclipse features expect the workspace to be available on a local path (so you can map a network drive, but not go to smb://fileserver/share or file:///path/to/file)

Comment: So would I use GIT to make sure my local files are synced up with what is on the development server? This way I am working locally. Thank you both for the feedback it is very helpful. I think I was overthinking the process.